# Custom Calendar in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, calendar

I want to add price value on the calendar under the date. Same as following image.

[image]

I have tried many 3rd party libraries like [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar), [JTCalendar](https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar), [awesome-ios-ui](https://github.com/cjwirth/awesome-ios-ui), but did not get succeed yet.

Is there any other library or solution for this.? I want to add a price label under the date on the Calendar.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which library you used?

Comment: use FSCalendar:
https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar

Comment: [there are plenty here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=calendar)

Comment: You should probably fork some 3rd party library you used and implement required functionality.

Comment: Custom make it by yourself. Here a tutorial. https://xcodenoobies.blogspot.my/2016/12/how-to-create-custom-objects-in-ios-apps.html

Comment: You can use this `https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui` and customize according to the need

Comment: `https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar` another one

Comment: You can use this https://github.com/jumartin/Calendar and it's customizable library

Comment: Go through this links https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar

https://github.com/klazuka/Kal

Comment: The other calendars may have failed, but you will succeed with this one.
--> [This awesome calendar](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar). With this library you can develop a calendar like this extremely easily.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use custom `UICollectionView` with number of section is 2 and and make sure number of cells in section 1 is 7 and number of cells in section is 42.
make a static array thats have weeks days name like
`arrOfWeekDayName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SUN",@"MON", @"TUE", @"WED", @"THU", @"FRI", @"SAT", nil];`

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView
{
return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (section == 0)
{
    return arrOfWeekDayName.count;
}
else{
    return 42;
    }
}
```

now take custom `UICollectionViewCell` one for show weeks days name 
and second for  show date with prize and images whatever you want to show in your cell.

for example i take two custom `UICollectionViewCell` first is `weekCell` and second is `dateCell`

`weekCell` have only one label which is show only days name
and `dateCell` have three property `lblDate`,`lblPrize`,`imgCell` and you add according your requirement.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
    weekCell *cell = (weekCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@“weekCell” forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.lblDay.text =[arrOfWeekDayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:63.0/255.0f green:65.0/255.0f blue:70.0/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    }
    return cell;
}
else
{
    dateCell *cell = (dateCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@“dateCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.lblDate.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12];
    cell.lblPrize.text= [NSString strngWithFormat:@“$5”];
    cell.imgCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@“myImage”];
 return cell;
}
}
```

when you fill the value of one month you need all values of this 42 cells 
and mange this cell according to months.
mange cells background colour according day

```
 FirstDateOfMonth = [CommonOps firstDayOfMonth:currentdate ];
    LastDateOfMonth = [CommonOps lastDayOfMonth:currentdate];
    if ([self date:date isEqualOrAfter:LastDateOfMonth])
    {
        cell.lblDateTitle.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        cell.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:209/256. green:209/256. blue:209/256. alpha:.5];
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = true;
    }
    else if ([self date: date isEqualOrBefore: FirstDateOfMonth])
    {
        cell.lblDateTitle.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        cell.backgroundColor =   [UIColor colorWithRed:209/256. green:209/256. blue:209/256. alpha:.5];
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor =   [UIColor colorWithRed:243/256. green:221/256. blue:159/256. alpha:.5];
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = true;
        if ([self date:currentdate isTheSameDayThan:date])
        {
            ValueToDisplayOnHeaderFirstTime = indexPath.row;
        }
        cell.lblDateTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 7 || indexPath.row == 14 || indexPath.row == 21 || indexPath.row == 28|| indexPath.row == 35 )
    {
        cell.backgroundColor =   [UIColor colorWithRed:250/256. green:195/256. blue:181/256. alpha:.5];
        cell.lblDateTitle.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
```

if you any confusion in this please let me know in comment section

Comment: nice solution, can you elaborate the  solution .....

Answer (score 1):

[JTAppleCalendar](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar) can build this for you (not to be confused with JTCalendar).

Seems to be well documented.
Easy setup.
If that library can't build your calendar for you, then i will be shocked. I literally builded my calendar (fully designed) in about 7 mins.

Documentation found [Here](http://patchthecode.github.io/)

Cocoapod link found [Here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/JTAppleCalendar)

Github link found [Here](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar)